# How do I set the default value of an exposed filter to a value that is not "-Any-"?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view with exposed filters, in Drupal 8. I need to set the default value of a filter to its title or custom text. I also need to unset/remove the *- Any -* option from the select list.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
    function bootstrap_barrio_subtheme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface 
    $form_state, $form_id) {
        if ($form_state['view'] == 'office_locations_doctor_detail') {
            $form['field_doctor_reference_target_id_1']['#default_value'] = 
            'Select Doctor';
        }
     }
```

Cleared the cache and reload the page but nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  You can do that by implementing hook_form_alter in a custom module or theme. And then I think you simply have to set the `'#default_value'` of this element. Have you tried that already?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function bootstrap_barrio_subtheme_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ( $form_state->get('view')->id() == 'office_locations_doctor_detail'){
     // Set the default value as tid not the name of term.
     // Change 'Select Doctor' by the tid of it.
    $form['field_doctor_reference_target_id_1']['#default_value'] = '1';
    // Remove - Any - option. 
    unset($form['field_doctor_reference_target_id_1']['#options']['All']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing is changed. Cleared the cache also.

Comment: if nothing changed, make sure that your theme name is `bootstrap_barrio_subtheme` and change the view name from àrticles` to your view name `office_locations_doctor_detail` for example, and make sure also the your field machine name is `field_doctor_reference_target_id_1`

Comment: check my update

Comment: Checked, but no effect.

Comment: I've achieved this by using Better Exposed Filter module.